# Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header in Azure Ratecard Apis

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

To fetch rate card, i'm using below api.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId+eq+{offer-id}+and+Currency+eq+'USD'+and+Locale+eq+'en-US'+and+RegionInfo+eq+'IN'
```

I was passing Authorization Header with value "Bearer eyioe..." in the request.
It was working earlier, but recently getting the below response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
    <Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
RequestId:5dc4ea49-b01e-00f9-6760-dcfb83000000
Time:2018-04-25T06:42:45.8106146Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, Check if  the `content type` in your request is `application/json`.

Comment: how did you acquire your access token?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT content type doesn't help. Token was aquired using adalj4 library

Comment: I have the same problem. Working in Postman, but not working in a C# application. While using the exact same bearer token and headers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the case is that RateCard API is sending back a 302 redirect. This is changed in a new release around the time of this question.

The recommended way to fix this is:

1. Get the bearer token,
2. Make request to ARM with Authentication Header set to the bearer token (this is the same as before)
3. RateCard will return a 302 status code which represents a redirect and contains a second URL from which fetch the ratecard from (this is new).
4. A second request must be made to second URL. Note that many http libraries will automatically follow the redirect and make the second request for you. When making the second request, the authorization header containing the bearer token needs to be removed, if it is not, you'll see the error. How this is actually implemented in your code will depend on which http client you're using. For C# the code is as follows:

---

```cs
const string subId = "Subscription Id here";
const string token = "Auth Token here.";

const string offer = "MS-AZR-0003P";
const string currency = "USD";
const string locale = "en-US";
const string region = "US";

using (var rateCardClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/") })
{
    rateCardClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
    var response = await rateCardClient.GetAsync($"subscriptions/{subId}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2016-08-31-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq '{offer}' and Currency eq '{currency}' and Locale eq '{locale}' and RegionInfo eq '{region}'");

    Console.WriteLine($"StatusCode:{response.StatusCode}");
    var ratecard = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.Write(ratecard);
}
```

See this Github issue page for more information: 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7423